# Cost optimization based on multiple variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

So I have a scenario that I'm trying to optimize. This is purely anecdotal and I need direction on the theories and considerations that would help solve the problem:

Say we have 4 companies (A-D) that provide workforce to a larger firm. Each company scores the productivity of the available workforce independently on a range from 1 to 100 (a score of 60 at company A may be a score of 30 at company B etc...). Each company also provides a labor rate that is independent of the productivity score (it is possible to have a high-cost, low producing worker on this list and vice versa).

The problem the larger firm has is that it wants to develop a multi-year plan where they select workers from the 4 lists. they must minimize the error from the budget (some over/under spending allowed, but not too much), maximize the productivity (higher producing  workers chosen first) each year, and minimizing the variance between the companies (all companies paid close to the equal amount). Once a worker is chosen it is removed from the list.

This reads like a non-linear optimization problem, but I'm unsure of specific theories, algorithms, etc. That could be used to solve this problem. Any sort of direction or a jumping off point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be formulated as a linear Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) model.

Here is my model:

[image]

The continuous variables are non-negative.

Let's try this out with some data.

```
----     34 PARAMETER cost  rate

              A           B           C           D

p1       58.587      92.163      77.519      65.057
p2       64.611      61.203      67.492      92.814
p3       53.356      75.011      99.906      78.937
p4       99.557      88.113      56.535      81.986
p5       57.976      62.504      83.446      71.768
p6       67.985      67.572      56.575      57.505
p7       79.456      91.545      61.541      83.287
p8       88.793      65.183      55.525      75.119
p9       58.009      93.623      63.256      64.291
p10      79.698      86.136      81.412      73.190
p11      70.665      55.885      65.711      52.328
p12      66.928      59.105      82.286      78.037
p13      88.498      64.890      83.055      87.791
p14      81.372      64.193                  54.321
p15      55.126      82.063                  77.265
p16                  51.576                  89.618
p17                  53.638                  58.783
p18                  76.282


----     34 PARAMETER budget               =     2500.000  available budget
            PARAMETER w1                   =        1.000  weight for budget error
            PARAMETER w2                   =        2.000  weight for range in amounts
```

I assume here that persons p are ordered by productivity: p1 is the most productive.

When I solve the model, the results look like:

```
----     89 PARAMETER costreport  

                    A           B           C           D        cost

p1             58.587      92.163      77.519      65.057
p2             64.611      61.203      67.492      92.814
p3             53.356      75.011      99.906      78.937
p4             99.557      88.113      56.535      81.986
p5             57.976      62.504      83.446      71.768
p6             67.985      67.572      56.575      57.505
p7             79.456      91.545      61.541      83.287
p8             88.793      65.183      55.525      75.119
p9             58.009                  63.256
total         628.328     603.293     621.793     606.472    2459.886
budget                                                       2500.000
budgeterr                                                      40.114
min                                                           603.293
max                                                           628.328
range                                                          25.036
```

We can see that the total cost is 2459.886, which means a deviation of about 40 from the budget. The amounts spent on each company has a range of 25 (range is maximum minus minimum). Also, note that persons are selected based on their order (remember we sorted users by decreasing productivity).

This is a simple MIP model that can be solved with any MIP solver.